# Azure bot: Unauthorized Access. Request is not authorized

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-bot-service, bot-emulator

I have a problem in implementing the Azure bot with the Azure web app.

the source of the web app is written in nodejs.

I have confirmed that the endpoint of the bot is right.

I have set BOT_ID and BOT_PASSWORD in the app configuration.

I tested on web chat and Bot emulator. both are not working.

The web app receives the request successfully. and all endpoints are configured. correctly.

I'm getting this error while debugging in the Bot emulator:

```json
{
  "value": "\"Unauthorized Access. Request is not authorized\""
}
```

I'm using VS code , with teams toolkit and azure service extension to deploy.

Comment: Did you register your app? Make sure you have the necessary permissions and scopes configured, and that you've granted consent as needed. Since you are using Azure App Service to host your bot, make sure that any authentication settings in App Service do not interfere with the authentication process.

Comment: @ZiyaMertKarakas Yes, the app is registered by the team's toolkit extension. also, I can see the registered app in the Azure portal. and I don't have any authentication settings in the App service. i have the owner permission for both app service and Azure bot service